# How do you deserialize a string with an enum where any other value deserializes into a newtype variant while preserving the string?

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

I have an enum similar to the following:

```rs
#[derive(Deserialize)]
enum ExampleEnum {
    #[serde(rename = "variant1-rename")]
    Variant1,
    #[serde(rename = "variant2-rename")]
    Variant2,
    Other(String),
}
```

It should deserialize like this:

| Serialized | Deserialized |
| --- | --- |
| `"variant1-rename"` | `ExampleEnum::Variant1` |
| `"variant2-rename"` | `ExampleEnum::Variant2` |
| `"foobar"` | `ExampleEnum::Other("foobar")` |

With my current code, the first two work as intended, but the last one does not, the program errors saying that it expected either "variant1-rename", "variant2-rename", or "Other".

It seems like the `#[serde(other)]` attribute would result in the desired behavior, but it can only be used with internally tagged or adjacently tagged enums.

The (JSON) data I am deserializing has a property that should be deserialized into the enum, so it would look like this:

```json
{
    "property": "variant1-rename"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code that solved the problem, based off of [Caesar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75091826/20876064) and the [Manually implementing Deserialize for a struct](https://serde.rs/deserialize-struct.html) page in `serde`'s documentation.

```rs
use serde::{ Deserialize, de };

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for ExampleEnum {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct ExampleEnumVisitor;

        impl<'de> de::Visitor<'de> for ExampleEnumVisitor {
            type Value = ExampleEnum;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("`variant1-rename`, `variant2-rename`, or some other string")
            }

            fn visit_str<E>(self, v: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
            where
                E: de::Error,
            {
                match v {
                    "variant1-rename" => Ok(ExampleEnum::Variant1),
                    "variant2-rename" => Ok(ExampleEnum::Variant2),
                    _ => Ok(ExampleEnum::Other(v.to_string())),
                }
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_identifier(ExampleEnumVisitor)
    }
}
```

If you wish for a shorter solution, use [Caesar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75091826/20876064). Read the comments under their solution to understand the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Besides opening a feature request to serde, I think the only way is to manually implement `Deserialize`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum ExampleEnum {
    Variant1,
    Variant2,
    Other(String),
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for ExampleEnum {
    fn deserialize<D>(de: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let variant = String::deserialize(de)?;
        Ok(match variant.as_str() {
            "variant1-rename" => ExampleEnum::Variant1,
            "variant2-rename" => ExampleEnum::Variant2,
            _other => ExampleEnum::Other(variant),
        })
    }
}
```

If you weren't renaming all your variants, you could probably make this a bit smoother with `enum_derive::FromStr`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! What's `Cow` though?

Comment: Moo. It avoids allocating a new `String` e.g. for `"variant1-rename"` and instead gives you a `&str` that's a substring of the input JSON (if it can. Sometimes, e.g. if the JSON is given as `"\u0076ariant1-rename"`, it still allocates - which makes it better than deserializing to `&str`, which would error out in this case.)

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I keep falling into this trap: Cow won't actually do its job until you mark it `#[serde(borrow)]`, which needs an extra wrapper struct. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a9858ec20492e4b99e021261ab2ef00) That's probably too much magic for the use-case and I've removed it from the answer, allocations are cheap, after all.

Comment: So I read the [Manually implementing Deserialize for a struct](https://serde.rs/deserialize-struct.html) page in `serde`'s documentation, and basically copied the implementation for `Field`. Is this better or worse than your code and why? Sorry if that's a bit much to ask, I just want to make sure I understand what's going on here. (I have a unit test set up and it passed, so my code does solve the problem.)

Comment: Depends. It's less concise, but it can give a better error message, and also achieves that no-superfluous-allocation thing which I tried to do with `Cow` but failed.

Comment: I think I’d rather go with that then, it seems like the more “official” way to do things. I’m a little new to Stack Overflow, should I post an answer with the code I’m using?

Comment: If you feel inclined to do so, post your code as an answer. It's certainly encouraged by SO.